# Compute Engine Snapshots can be used in other platforms

Tags: google-compute-engine

Can I use my Snapshots in GCP Compute engine in other platforms or even on premise setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute engine Snapshots can be exported to other platforms. Just make sure that the format you are using is working with the environment that you are going to use.

Comment: This is a loaded answer. It is one thing to export a snapshot and copy the raw data to a disk. It is an entirely different matter to get the raw data to boot. Google Cloud Compute Engine images are missing drivers required to run on most platforms. Issues such as MBR versus EFI, BIOS, firmware, boot loaders and drivers are not minor issues to solve. Therefore, the answer is yes you can but you better have the knowledge to successfully do it.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all formats are available and also bear in mind that when migrating OS,  make sure you have the corresponding license is applicable to avoid issues.